# Plugin always only gets last instance, how to make it work for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Here in the code i am trying to call this plugin for 2 div elements. But i am only able to see the effects in the last instance only. I see that all the elements coming in the each loop but when i use the window resize event i face this issue.

Can someonle please point out what the issue is? I am using the jqueryboilerplate template for this plugin 
Here is the jquery plugin code. Just copy paste this in your html file and it will work.

```
    // the semi-colon before function invocation is a safety net against concatenated
// scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed properly.
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    "use strict";

    // undefined is used here as the undefined global variable in ECMAScript 3 is
    // mutable (ie. it can be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really being
    // passed in so we can ensure the value of it is truly undefined. In ES5, undefined
    // can no longer be modified.

    // window and document are passed through as local variable rather than global
    // as this (slightly) quickens the resolution process and can be more efficiently
    // minified (especially when both are regularly referenced in your plugin).

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = "vf_resizer",
    defaults = {
        propertyName: "value"
    };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin ( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.$element = $( element );
        // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
        // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
        // future instances of the plugin
        this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    // Avoid Plugin.prototype conflicts
    $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
        init: function () {
            // Place initialization logic here
            // You already have access to the DOM element and
            // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element
            // and this.settings
            // you can add more functions like the one below and
            // call them like so: this.yourOtherFunction(this.element, this.settings).
            // console.log(this);
            this.cycle();
        },
        cycle: function () {
            // some logic
            //console.log(this);

            this.resize_calculator();



        },

        resize_calculator : function (){

            self = this

            $(window).resize(function() { 

                console.log(self);
                self.$element.each(function (index, value){
                    console.log(value);
                })


                self.$element.children().each(function (index, value){

                    var $parent_selector = self.$element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

                    var factors = {};
                    var parent = {};
                    var current_dimensions = {};

                    factors.w = $(this).data('w-factor');
                    factors.h = $(this).data('h-factor');

                    factors.posx = $(this).data('posx-factor');
                    factors.posy = $(this).data('posy-factor');


                    parent.width =  $parent_selector.width;
                    parent.height =  $parent_selector.width/2.4;


                    current_dimensions.left = parent.width * factors.posx;        
                    current_dimensions.top = parent.height * factors.posy;        


                    current_dimensions.width = parent.width * factors.w;        
                    current_dimensions.height = parent.height * factors.h;   



                    self.resize_elements(this, current_dimensions, parent);

                })
            });
        },

        resize_elements : function (element, dimensions, parent){
            // console.log(element);
            self = this;
            console.log(self);
            self.$element.css({height: parent.height})       

            $( element ).css({
                position : "absolute",  
                left : dimensions.left,
                top:  dimensions.top,
                height: dimensions.height,
                width: dimensions.width
            });  
        }
    });

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function() {
            //console.log($.data);
            if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
               // console.log(this);
                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
            }
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

here is the html code.

```
 <body>

    <style>
        .resizer{ position : relative; border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; height:300px;}
        .deeplink1{position: absolute; top:0; left: 300px; border: 1px solid blue; width: 50%; height: 100px;}
        .deeplink2{position: absolute; top:100px; left: 0; border: 1px solid blue; width: 50%; height: 100px;}
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {


            $("#one").vf_resizer();
            $("#two").vf_resizer();

           /* $(".resizer").vf_resizer();*/
        });
    </script>







    <div id="one" class="resizer">
        <div id="drag1" class="deeplink1" data-posx-factor='0.25' data-posy-factor='0' data-h-factor='0.33' data-w-factor='0.5'></div>
        <div id="drag2" class="deeplink2" data-posx-factor='0' data-posy-factor='0.33' data-h-factor='0.33' data-w-factor='0.5'></div>
        <!--<div id="drag3" class="deeplink" data-posx-factor='0.5' data-posy-factor='0.5' data-h-factor='0.1' data-w-factor='0.2'></div>-->
    </div>




    <div id="two" class="resizer">
        <div id="drag3" class="deeplink1" data-posx-factor='0.25' data-posy-factor='0' data-h-factor='0.33' data-w-factor='0.5'></div>
        <div id="drag4" class="deeplink2" data-posx-factor='0' data-posy-factor='0.33' data-h-factor='0.33' data-w-factor='0.5'></div>
        <!--<div id="drag3" class="deeplink" data-posx-factor='0.5' data-posy-factor='0.5' data-h-factor='0.1' data-w-factor='0.2'></div>-->
    </div>



</body>
```

UPDATE 1: This plugin is supposed to resize the elements in the div resizer according to the windows size. I have added their factors in the data attributes to pick them up from there.

UPDATE 2: Here is the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/5he2n2rb/

Comment: It would help if you breifly explained what the plugin is supposed to do

Comment: i just updated what the plugin does

Comment: I couldnt find the issue but here is a jsfiddle if someone else wants to take a crack at it http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/5he2n2rb/ , open the console  then resize the window, you'll see the log messages and notice the poblem. It's like each element overwrites the last in your plugin like its not setup to work with a collection of elements but rather just one.

Comment: Thats exactly what i am facing.

Comment: Resizing layout with jQuery is very slow and resource consuming. Is this something that can't be done with a CSS fluid layout? Even with Flexbox?

Comment: yes, i agree. But the divs in the resizer div will be created dynamically by the user so there is no way i can know how to adjust the layout using css

Comment: Was anyone able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but in the plugin i found a `;` at a place where it does not seems to be:

```
current_dimensions.width = parent.width * factors.w;        
current_dimensions.height = parent.height * factors.h;   

; // <------this one should not have to be here.

self.resize_elements(this, current_dimensions, parent);
```

and i can see you don't have jquery  reference on your html page.

Comment: Jai, thats a typo, i removed it from the question now

Comment: the jquery reference is there i just consider that to be understood, Did you get what i was asking btw?